# Autoboxing a character value and then returning a blank value

Tags: java, random, char, character, autoboxing

I have this piece of code  that generates a random characters (ASCII)

```
public char getRandChar(){ return (char)rand.nextInt(27); }
```

and then I'll print it out using this

```
System.out.println(new Character(getRandChar()));
```

How but apparently it is returning a blank value

Comment: maybe you are getting a non-printing ASCII character

Comment: You're generating a character whose ASCII value is between 0 and 26, and these are all non-printing characters.  If your intention was to print a random letter of the alphabet, then you should probably add 'A' to your integer instead of directly casting it to (char).

Comment: @DavidWallace you're right, it is returning a non-printing character, a little question, why should I add an 'A'?  rather than just this? (char) rand.nextInt(25) + 65?

Comment: Adding 65 is equivalent to adding 'A'.  But your program will be easier for future maintainers to understand if you have 'A' in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `rand.nextInt(27);` is returning unprintable character codes. This will be evident if you change your code to `return (char)65;` for example.